# How do I 'cd' to a symbolically linked directory that says "Permission denied"?

Tags: linux, permissions, symlink

I currently have two users on my Linux OS for two different DE's. However, I'd like to remove file duplicity as much as possible between the accounts. Specifically, I've been trying to link the `~/german-capstone` folder from the user `segeeslice` to `lucifer`.

To do this, as `lucifer`, I called:

```
ln -s /home/segeeslice/german-capstone /home/lucifer/
```

It functions as expected, putting the link in the right place. However, trying to access it throws errors like:

```
bash: cd: german-capstone: Permission denied
```

I understand this is likely just a permissions issue, but I can't find where the source is! I've gone as far as giving both sides full access to the folder and its contents, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

<s>[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPTD.png) are the permissions to the **source directory**</s>
<s>[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNYn0.png) are the permissions to the **symbolic link**</s>

---

In response to a comment, here is the full list of permissions:

```
------ /home/lucifer/german-capstone ------

    drwxr-xr-x  755 root     root     /
    drwxr-xr-x  755 root     root     /home
    drwxr--r--  744 lucifer  lucifer  /home/lucifer
    lrwxrwxrwx  777 lucifer  lucifer  /home/lucifer/german-capstone
                                      -> /home/segeeslice/german-capstone
    drwxr--r--  744 segeeslice segeeslice /home/segeeslice
    drwxrwxrwx  777 segeeslice segeeslice /home/segeeslice/german-capstone
```

The higher levels still have the right read properties... do I need to give more permissions somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the permissions anywhere up the path to either source directory or symlink, including also any other symlinks which are encountered in the paths to these things.

Here is a script that will show all those permissions for you.  It will show the permissions on everything from the root directory down to the path in question, and if it encounters the symlink then it will start again based on the link target, except that it won't repeat the output for any directory that it has already shown you (so for example the permissions on `/` are only ever shown once).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;


my $usage=<<EOF;
Usage: $0 file [file ...]

 Shows permissions on every path component from root directory to the named
 file(s), including paths traversed while following symlinks.

 Also shows permissions and contents of any .ftpaccess or .htaccess files
 encountered.

 If multiple files are specified, gives a listing for them all, but for later
 files does not show again the permissions on a path component already shown
 for earlier files.

EOF
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

use Cwd;
my $cwd = cwd;
chomp $cwd;

if ($#ARGV==-1) {
    print $usage;
    exit 1;
};

my @history=();
my @accessfiles=();

# loop over files on command line.
FILE: foreach my $fullpath (@ARGV) {

    # prepend cwd if relative path
    $fullpath="$cwd/$fullpath" unless $fullpath =~ /^\//;

    # fix pathname..
    $fullpath=stripslashes($fullpath);

    print "\n------ $fullpath ------\n\n";

    my $len=length $fullpath;
    my $pos=-1;
    my @targets=($fullpath);

    ELEMENT: while ($pos<$len) {

    # get full pathname of next element (etc)

    my $stem=($pos>=0) ? substr($fullpath,0,$pos) : ''; # parent

    $pos=index($fullpath,'/',$pos+1);
    $pos=$len if $pos==-1;
    my $path=($pos>0) ? substr($fullpath,0,$pos) : '/';

    my $remainder=substr($fullpath,$pos);

    #
    # stat the path element.
    #
    my @stat=lstat($path);
    my $okay=($#stat != -1);

    # tidy up as follows:
    #   if trailing "/foo/.." or "/." strip it and move to next element.
    #
    # We can do this because at this stage "foo" isn't a link,
    #  or we would already have followed it, but only do it if stat
    #  succeeded as parent might not be a directory (in that case, the
    #  error trap later will be executed).
    #
    my ($newpath, $subst);
    if ($okay) {
        $subst=1;   
        if ( $path =~ /\.\.$/ ) {       
        if ($stem eq '') {
            $newpath='/';
            $fullpath=$remainder;
        } else {
            ($newpath = $stem) =~ s,/([^/]*?)$,, ;
            $fullpath=$newpath.$remainder;
            if ($newpath eq '') {$newpath='/';}
        }
        }
        elsif ( $path =~ /\.$/ ) {
        if ($stem eq '') {
            $newpath='/';
            $fullpath=$remainder;
        } else {
            $newpath = $stem;
            $fullpath=$newpath.$remainder;
        }
        }
        else {
        $subst=0;
        }
        if ($subst) {
        $path=$newpath;
        $pos=length $path;
        $len=length $fullpath;
        next ELEMENT;
        }
    }

    # have we been here before?
    my $beenthere=grep {$_ eq $path} @history;
    push @history,$path;

    # is it a symlink?
    if (-l _) {

        # yes. see where it points
        my $pointsto=readlink $path;
        my $newfile;
        if ($pointsto =~ /^\//) {
        # link is absolute pathname
        $newfile=$pointsto.substr($fullpath,$pos);
        $pos=-1;
        } else {
        # link is relative pathname
        $newfile=$stem.'/'.$pointsto.substr($fullpath,$pos);
        $pos=length $stem;
        }
        if (!$beenthere) {
        show_stat(\@stat,$path,$pointsto);
        }
        # strip extra "/"
        $newfile=stripslashes($newfile);

        # check for recursive links
        my $beenthere2=grep {$_ eq $newfile} @targets;
        push @targets,$newfile;
        if ($beenthere2) {
        print " === SYMLINK LOOP DETECTED ===\n";
        next FILE;
        }
        # follow the link (stripping extra "/"s)
        $fullpath=$newfile;
        $len=length $fullpath;
    } else {
        # no, not a symlink
        # print info, with usernames/groupnames where possible
        # unless we've been here before...
        if (!$beenthere) {
        if (! $okay) {
            print "\n*** ERROR : $path : $! ***\n";
            next FILE;
        }
        show_stat(\@stat,$path);

        #
        # check for any {.htaccess,.ftpaccess} files
        # 
        for my $name (qw(.htaccess .ftpaccess)) {
            my $file = "$path/$name";
            if (-e $file) {
            push @accessfiles,$file;
            }
        }
        }       
    }
    } # end ELEMENT loop
} # end FILE loop
continue {    
    print "\n";
}

if ($#accessfiles > -1) {
    print "Access control files of possible relevance:\n\n";
    for my $file (@accessfiles) {
    my @stat = stat($file);
    show_stat(\@stat,$file);
    if (open my $access,$file) {
        print "\n    ---- Contents of $file ----\n";
        while (defined (my $line=<$access>)){
        chomp $line;
        print "    $line\n";
        }
        close $access;
        print "    ------- End of $file -------\n";
    } else {
        print "    Could not open $file: $!\n";
    }
    }
    print "\n";
}

exit 0;

#-------------------------------------------------------------
sub stripslashes 
{    
    my $line = shift;

    # strip trailing or repeated '/'s
    $line =~ s,/*$,,;
    $line =~ s,//+,/,g;
    $line =~ s,^$,/,;

    return $line;
}

sub show_stat
{
    use Fcntl ':mode';

    my ($stat,$path,$linktarget) = @_;

    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
    $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = @$stat;


    my @pwent=getpwuid($uid);
    my $username=($#pwent == -1) ? "($uid)" : $pwent[0];
    my @grent=getgrgid($gid);
    my $grpname=($#grent == -1) ? "($gid)" : $grent[0];
    printf ("%s %4o %-8s %-8s %s\n",
        symbolic_mode($mode),
        $mode&07777,$username,$grpname,$path);

    if (S_ISLNK($mode) and defined($linktarget)) {
    print "                                  -> $linktarget\n";
    }

}

sub symbolic_mode
{
    # takes a numerical mode returned by stat,
    # returns a symbolic string as per "ls -l"
    # e.g. for 0640 returns "-rw-r-----"

    my $mode = shift;

    use Fcntl ':mode';

    my $typechar = 
    S_ISREG($mode) ? '-' :
    S_ISDIR($mode) ? 'd' :
    S_ISLNK($mode) ? 'l' :
    S_ISBLK($mode) ? 'b' :
    S_ISCHR($mode) ? 'c' :
    S_ISFIFO($mode) ? 'p' :
    S_ISSOCK($mode) ? 's' : 
    '?';

    my $modestr = $typechar . 'rwxrwxrwx';
    for (my $bit=0; $bit <= 8 ; $bit++) {
    if (($mode & (1<<$bit)) == 0) {
        substchar(\$modestr,9-$bit,"-");
    }
    }
    if ($mode & 01000) {
    substchar(\$modestr,9,
          ($mode & 0001) ? "t" : "T");
    }
    if ($mode & 02000) {
    substchar(\$modestr,6,
          ($mode & 0010) ? "s" : "S");
    }
    if ($mode & 04000) {
    substchar(\$modestr,3,
          ($mode & 0100) ? "s" : "S");
    }    
    return $modestr;
}

sub substchar
{
    # substitutes a character in a string
    my ($sref, $pos, $newchar) = @_;
    my $string = $$sref;
    my $newstring = substr($string,0,$pos) . $newchar . substr($string,$pos+1);
    $$sref=$newstring;
}
```

example output:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/mydir/stuff
$ ln -s stuff /tmp/mydir/stuff2
$ cal > /tmp/mydir/stuff2/myfile
$ mkdir /tmp/mydir2
$ ls /tmp/mydir2/stuff2/myfile
ls: cannot access '/tmp/mydir2/stuff2/myfile': No such file or directory
$ ls /tmp/mydir/stuff2/
myfile
$ ln -s /tmp/mydir/stuff2/myfile  /tmp/mydir/stuff2/thingy
$ chmod 700 /tmp/mydir
$ permsto  /tmp/mydir/stuff2/thingy

------ /tmp/mydir/stuff2/thingy ------

drwxr-xr-x  755 root     root     /
drwxrwxrwt 1777 root     root     /tmp
drwx------  700 myuser   mygroup  /tmp/mydir
lrwxrwxrwx  777 myuser   mygroup  /tmp/mydir/stuff2
                                  -> stuff
drwxr-xr-x  755 myuser   mygroup  /tmp/mydir/stuff
lrwxrwxrwx  777 myuser   mygroup  /tmp/mydir/stuff/thingy
                                  -> /tmp/mydir/stuff2/myfile
-rw-r--r--  644 myuser   mygroup  /tmp/mydir/stuff/myfile
```

So you can look at the output and see at a glance where any permissions problem is lurking.

---

Now that the question has been updated to include the output of the script on the directory in question, it is clear that the issue is with the permissions on the following directories:

```
    drwxr--r--  744 lucifer  lucifer  /home/lucifer
    drwxr--r--  744 segeeslice segeeslice /home/segeeslice
```

Where a process has read but not execute access to a directory, it will be able to list the directory but not otherwise access any paths contained within it.  For a directory with octal mode 744, this will be the case for any processes not running as the owner (or root), which will be reliant on the "group" or "other" permissions.  If it is changed to octal mode 755 (i.e. add execute permission for "group" and "other"), then these will have the necessary access.

Comment: This is code that I wrote back in 1998 and am happy to share it for people to use as-is or to adapt for themselves, but sorry I am not offering to maintain / improve it now.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the post with the outputs of this script

Comment: And I can see the problem. I will edit my answer with what it is.

Comment: @segeeslice Please see new text at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That works, I've marked it as solved.

However, why does this path need execute permissions for `cd`? I thought that only pertained to executing scripts within the folder

Comment: @segeeslice Any access to a directory other than merely listing the contents requires execute permission. This includes a `cd` to the directory itself, and it certainly includes a `cd` (or any other access) to any subdirectories.

Comment: @segeeslice Note also that even an `ls -l` of a directory will require execute permission, because it needs access in order to check the permissions on the files contained with in. The only thing you can do with only read permission is basically a plain `ls`. So 744 on a directory is not often useful. What _is_ sometimes more useful is 711 (granting execute but not read permission), so that people can access the contents but only if they already know the name, but cannot list the directory to find it.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Thanks again